# Extjs 4 grid combobox store from dataIndex

Tags: javascript, extjs4

I am so sorry, because I don't know what this called. I have a grid like this,
please look this screenshot:
[the screen shot](http://prntscr.com/1mbb91)

I have created the combobox in the 'position' column, but how can I set the store from the 'available position' column?

Answer (score 0):

Using columnCfgs you can create a renderer - the third parameter to this function is the record getting passed into the grid.  The renderer function requires a 'return' statement so try returning a combobox whose store contains the data from record.availablePosition or whatever name the data is stored under.

Here's an example of using a renderer (3 different times):
[image]

Which comes from this github code: [Blocking History](https://github.com/Beamanator/BlockingHistory/blob/master/App.js)